# The output image is not converted to sepia. What is wrong with my sepia code?

Tags: c, filter, cs50

I really can't find what's the problem with my code here. The output image is not even converting to sepia at all; it's kind of like grayscale and has pinkish sky. The algorithm I applied is correct and I did use the round function implemented in math.h. I guess there might be something wrong with my if-else statements?

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //process pixels by row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //process a single pixel in a row
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
           //implement the algorithm
           float sepiaRed = 0.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        
            //round sepiaRed
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);
            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
            else
            {
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            }
        
            float sepiaGreen = 0.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        
            //round sepiaGreen
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            }
        
            float sepiaBlue = 0.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            //round sepiaBlue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sepiaBlue);
            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
            else
            {
               image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            }
       }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is `image` an array of `unsigned char`? If it is, no element is ever going to be greater than 255: unsigned arithmetic wraps around (`(unsigned char)((unsigned char)100 + (unsigned char)200)` yields `44`)

Comment: Yes, I can see that. An array of `RGBTRIPLE`. What is `RGBTRIPLE` made of?

Comment: @ pmg I'm not sure. The problem is from https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/4/filter/less/, it comes with a bunch of .h and .c filers which I have only a little understanding about them, but my job is to write code for the filters.

Comment: I mean: if `image[i][j].rgbtRed` is an `unsigned char` assigning more than `255` to it will wrap around (`image[i][j].rgbtRed = 280;` effectively is `image[i][j].rgbtRed = 24;`)

Comment: @ pmg It's made of BYTE  rgbtBlue; BYTE  rgbtGreen; BYTE  rgbtRed;

Comment: The whole definition of RGBTRIPLE is typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

Comment: `BYTE` is, very probably, an alias for `unsigned char` (the C standard does not define `BYTE`)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information provided in my post. BYTE is defined as uint8_t.

Comment: Ok, `uint8_t` is definitely wrapping around after 255. If you assign some large value to a variable of that type (`image[i][j].rgbtRed = 263;`) it wraps around (to `7`)

Comment: What is the purpose of lines like `image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;`?  My eyes are old, but it looks like  LHS ==  RHS and that is a no-op.  Is there a typo?

Comment: @WilliamPursell ... to "fill the `else`", it's redundant and very probably removed by the compiler

Comment: @ pmg oh no...Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @ William Pursell   I was trying to tell the computer not to change the value in image[i][j].rgbtBlue if it is less than 256...Obviously, that statement doesn't make sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:
`image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);`
I assume that `rgbtRed` is 8-bit long unsigned integer (usually called "byte"). Therefore this operation will leave only 8 least significant bits of rounded part of `sepiaRed`. The rest of bits will be truncated during conversion to 8 bit integer.

The checks later on like:

```
if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
```

make no sense because 8-bit unsigned integer can represent number form 0-255 range. It's not possible for it to be larger than 255.

Moreover, the line below looks quite redundant:

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
```

The correct solution should apply limitation to the *float* value and next round it and store to 8-bit integer.

```
if (sepiaGreen > 255)
  sepiaGreen = 255;
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
```

---

Another problem.
Compute all sepia components **BEFORE** updating `image[i][j]`.
Otherwise `sepiaRed` would be used as `rgbtRed` during computation of `sepiaGreen`.

---

The final code for the body of the inner loop could be:

```
// extract color component for give pixel
float r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
float g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
float b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

// compute sepia components
float sepiaRed   = 0.393 * r + 0.769 * g + 0.189 * b;
float sepiaGreen = 0.349 * r + 0.686 * g + 0.168 * b;
float sepiaBlue  = 0.272 * r + 0.534 * g + 0.131 * b;

// truncate to 0-255
if (sepiaRed   > 255) sepiaRed   = 255;
if (sepiaGreen > 255) sepiaGreen = 255;
if (sepiaBlue  > 255) sepiaBlue  = 255;

// round and store
image[i][j].rgbtRed   = round(sepiaRed);
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = round(sepiaBlue);
```

Comment: Could you further extand the explaination on "image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);" Like, why they the the least signifcant bits? And yeah, I do feel like "image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;" has some problem. For the limitation part, do you mean I have to create an int variable for image[i][j].rgbtRed, one for image[i][j].rgbtGreen and another one for image[i][j].rgbtBlue?

Comment: @Sherri, see update answer

Comment: Thank you so much! And one more question, why it's not going to give me the correct output image if I just compute one sepia component and then update the corresponding RGB value of image[i][j]? How is it different computing all sepia components before updating image[i][j]?

Comment: @Sherri, because in the original code to compute `sepiaGreen` you used `image[i][j].rgbtRed` which was already updated a few line before. As result the value of `sepiaGreen` would be different from the one computed from original `image[i][j].rgbtRed` . It's common problem with many "in-place" operations where input and output are the same image.

Comment: Now I see why the order of those statements are significant. I feel like there are a lot of problems you can run into when writing a program and it requires the programmer to be very circumspectant to avoid them. Anyway, I really appreciate your help and time!